# Reducing namespace by using classes in python

Tags: python

Since classes is an abstract concept for storing data and methods. I was wondering whether we could use this to reduce number of variables defined in the local namespace.

My question is:
When you multiple variables e.g. 10 that are relevant to one main topic.
E.g. Details of a person called Jack, and you have descriptions about the person
name, age, occupation and so on.

is it a good idea to create a class?

```
class Jack: pass

jack = Jack() 

jack.age = 30

jack.occupation = work
```

And possibly have class `Jack` inherit from class `Person`. i.e `class Jack(Person): pass`

This would help reduce the number of variables taking up the namespace usage.
since you wouldn't have to write:
`jack_age` and so on.

or am i missing the point?

Comment: "And possibly have class Jack inherit from class Person" No. Just have a `Person` class with a name instance attribute.

Comment: It's helpful here to think about the name "class".  It's intended to represent a class of objects, a group with similar properties that can be represented the same way.  As there's (probably) only one Jack in your example, you don't need to have a class `Jack`, just an instance of `Person`  `jack = Person(30, 'Programmer')`

Comment: Jack appears to be data, you shouldn't expect to need to change your code everytime data is changed.. i.e Jack has a birthday, changes profession, name, gender...

Comment: I see that would make sense. So you would want `self.age`, `self.occupation` etc. in `class Person`. So then you create an object called `jack = Person()`

Comment: You were on the right track, because you wanted to get rid of `jack_age`. But this is not a reason to create a class for the object, but to create a class for a classification of that object (e.g. person). And please note, since 'Jack' is also an attribute of one person, it should not (only) be the instance name, but the value of a variable 'name'.

Comment: Thanks for your input everyone, much appreciated :).

Answer (score 0):

Classes are a good choice for that kind of variable management, but on a slightly wider scope than you defined; you shouldn't create a class for `Jake`, because `Jake` is an object, a being, of the type `Person`, not a type by itself.

That is why you should create a class `Person` and an instance of `Person` called `Jake`, rather than an instance of `Jake`; `Jake` is merely a human being, a person. He is not a general type for describing `Jack`s.

I would go with

```
class Occupation:
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name

class Person:
    def __init__ (self, name, age, occupation):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.occupation = occupation

work = Occupation('fireman')
jack = Person('Jack', 30, work) 

print('{} is {} years old and works as a {}'.format(
    jack.name, jack.age, jack.occupation.name))
```

Comment: I think this is a good approach, do you think a `class Occupation` itself would be unnecessary unless you wanted to define more variables inside it.

Comment: Well, it sepends on your views. OOP is best when you describe with it as you do in real life. Occupation is a general type, which you may expand to include salary, address, phone etc., and as such, it is worthy of defining as class; but for that example, you might leave it away and use `Person('Jack', 30, 'fireman') `